# No newline at end of file Error appears when i run the program

Tags: c, file, gcc

I am using gcc compiler through the terminal of linux run a program. The University that i  in, gave us a file with tests. We should run these tests on our programs and the tests should pass. I compile my program with gcc through terminal and it doesnt come back with any errors.I run the tests, the test results are correct but it says that i failed because there is No newline at end of file

For example. The test gibes out the result:
Secret
The result is Secret but it says that i failed because of the error mentioned.
How can i fix it?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
        int i,j;
        char k='a', arr[5][5];
        for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
         for (j=0; j<=4; j++)
           {
                  arr[i][j]= k;
                        k= ++ k;
                 if(k=='j')
                   k= ++k;
            }
   }
   char str[74],str2[74], *p;
        fgets(str,75,stdin);
        for(i=0; i<75; i++)
          str2[i]=str[i];
        p=strtok(str,"-");
        while(p!=NULL)
        {        
          if(atoi(p)/10>4||atoi(p)%10>4)
           {
            printf("Out of bounds\n");
                return 0;
           }
          else if (isalpha(*p))
       {
                printf("Unable to decode\n");
            return 0;
       }
       p=strtok(NULL,"-");  
    }
        p=strtok(str2,"-");
        printf("< ");
        while(p!=NULL)
          {
          printf("%c", arr[atoi(p)/10][atoi(p)%10]);    
          p=strtok(NULL, "-");
      }
printf("\n");
return 0
}
```

[image]

Comment: Open your source file in an editor. Go to the last line. Press the `Enter` key to make sure there's an empty line at the end of it. Rebuild and rerun the tests.

Comment: Did you write the code? Then share it if you want help

Comment: Is the complaint that the source file does not end with a new-line character or that the output does not end with a new-line character?

Comment: When the tests says _"No newline at end of file"_, which file is that?

Comment: What happens if you add a newline to your output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  We need to see the code and data to be able to help — create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  Make sure that you print each line of output with a newline at the end of the format string.  Or add a `putchar('\n');` or `putc('\n', fp);` at the end.

Comment: Can you confirm that you did the obvious thing and added newlines in all the places you could think of? Did that change anything? Where did you add newlines? We can then help with guessing what you missed.

Comment: I pressed Enter at the end of the programs but nothing really happened

Comment: You have: `char str[74], …; fgets(str,75,stdin);` — and there are two significant problems with that.  (1) You tell `fgets()` it has more space to use than it actually has; use `sizeof(str)` in this context, where the array definition is visible.  In other circumstances, you may have to pass the size of the array to the location where it is used as a parameter.  (2) You don't check the return value from `fgets()` but simply assume it succeeded.  You should check that it was successful before using the result.  Separately, the total lack of consistent indentation makes for hard reading.

Comment: Pressing Enter does not add anything to your output. Did you add a `\n` to your output?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do but try this fixed up version of your code. Looks like it expects input something like `1-2-3`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    char k='a', arr[5][5];
    for (i=0; i<=4; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<=4; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = k++;
            if(k=='j')
                k++;
         }
    }
    char str[75],str2[75], *p;
    fgets(str,75,stdin);
    for(i=0; i<75; i++)
        str2[i]=str[i];
    while(p!=NULL) {        
        printf("p=%c\n", *p);
        if(atoi(p)/10>4||atoi(p)%10>4) {
            printf("Out of bounds\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (isalpha(*p)) {
            printf("Unable to decode\n");
            return 0;
        }
        p=strtok(NULL,"-");  
    }
    p=strtok(str2,"-");
    printf("< ");
    while(p!=NULL) {
        printf("%c", arr[atoi(p)/10][atoi(p)%10]);    
        p=strtok(NULL, "-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The main changes are:

1. Adding a couple of missing `#include`s
2. Error in initial population of `arr`
3. Sizing of `str` and `str2` should be 75 not 74. The setting of `str2` was overwriting `p`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer people.The problem wasnt the fact that i didn't put \n . I put the \n  and the error still appeared.The problem was that i put the \n. Basically the error appeared because the \n was there, not because \n was missing. Thank you so much for the help and your time